# Why IE document mode is Edge in one environment and IE5 in another

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, tomcat, web-applications

I have a web page that renders correctly when document mode is Edge, but have some issues when document mode is IE5. This page is part of a web application that is deployed on a tomcat server (if that is a relevant info).

When I test this on my development environment the doc mode is Edge. I can see this when I click on Emulation Tab in F12 Developer Tools. See [Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNd4A.jpg). This is when my web application is deployed on my local tomcat server. But when I deploy the same web application on another test environment with same version of tomcat server and access the page doc mode is IE5. Please note that I am using the same browser i.e IE11 to access page on both environments.

Now I understand that the way to force browser to load web page in Edge mode is to add following

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I have not included the above in my html. But why does my browser load the page from my dev env in Edge mode while from the test env in IE5 mode. What is the difference? The code is same, tomcat server is same. How is browser interpreting diff env differently.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer defaults to showing *intranet* documents in "compatibility" (read: broken) mode, and has various lists of sites that you can add to to say "no, no, work correctly with this site/URL/etc. please." It also has a "service" it will use if you let it that tells it which intranet sites to use in "compatibility" mode.

It would appear that you've at some point told IE not to hobble itself in your dev environment, but not told it not to hobble itself in your test environment.

Add the `meta` tag you've quoted to the top of the `head` of the document to make this not an environment-specific thing.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.